# "Cannot process argument transformation" when creating PSCredential

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-authentication

I'm trying to create a Windows credential by calling PowerShell from C# using the code below:

```
using var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in clearTextPassword)
   securePassword.AppendChar(c);
securePassword.MakeReadOnly();

var credential = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("New-Object")
                .AddParameter("TypeName", "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential")
                .AddParameter("ArgumentList", new object[] { "mydomain\\myuser", securePassword }) // String, SecureString
                .Invoke();
```

When the credential line above is executed I get this Exception:

**Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName**

I'm stumped as to why and can't find any relevant C# examples for doing this (or at least none showing how to do it differently). I'm guessing it's something rather simple, like naming the arguments, but not sure how that's done.

**EDIT 1:**

Running the following in PowerShell (using `New-Object`):

```
$user = "MyDomain\MyAccount"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pass
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\server\share" -Credential $cred -Persist
```

Fails with this error:
**New-PSDrive : The specified network password is not correct**

But when I modify to prompt the user for the same password (using `Get-Credential`):

```
$user = "MyDomain\MyAccount"
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential $user
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\server\share" -Credential $cred -Persist
```

It works. Note that in both cases I'm specifying the same plain-text password. I can only assume that `ConvertTo-SecureString` is not working as expected.

**EDIT 2:**

Finally figured out the script problem in EDIT 1. I switched to using a single-quote (') around the plain-text password instead of a double-quote ("). A string enclosed in single-quotation marks is a *verbatim* string. The string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed. My real password (different from what I showed here) had dollar sign characters in it which I presume were being interpreted as variables.

More information about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1).

Still doesn't resolve my original question regarding the C# code though.

Comment: Maybe try `PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("New-Object")
                .AddParameter("TypeName", "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential").AddArgument("mydomain\\myuser").AddArgument(securePassword)`  This seems to work as expected in powershell `New-Object -TypeName pscredential  $cred.UserName, $cred.Password`

Comment: @Daniel That gives me this error: "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]". Strangely, when I run this in PowerShell manually there is no error: `$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList MyDomain\MyAccount, $pw`. So it has something to do with calling it from C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below seems to be working:

```
var pw = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("ConvertTo-SecureString")
    .AddParameter("String", MyPassword)
    .AddParameter("AsPlainText")
    .AddParameter("Force")
    .Invoke();

var credential = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("New-Object")
    .AddParameter("TypeName", "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential")
    .AddParameter("ArgumentList", new object[] { @"MyDomain\MyAccount", pw[0] }) // String, SecureString
    .Invoke();

//var credential = new PSCredential(@"MyDomain\MyAccount, securePassword); // Another way

var r = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("New-PSDrive")
    .AddParameter("Name", "X")
    .AddParameter("PSProvider", "FileSystem")
    .AddParameter("Root", @"\\MyServer\MyShare")
    .AddParameter("Credential", credential[0])
    .AddParameter("Persist")
    .Invoke();
```

They key was using `pw[0]` and `credential[0]`.

Now the remaining problem I have is the above only works under my creds. If I try to get credentials for a different account and map the drive that way, it fails. That might be a Windows limitation though. Will keep playing with it.